# Function is not working with onEdit() and error message said "Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, oauth-2.0

I'm using a google apps script with a google spread sheet, connect with BigQuery.
I'm trying to insert data if the user input data from the Google spreadsheet.

I could insert the data through function but I couldn't insert the data through the onEdit() function.

The error message is this :

*GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
*

This insertOrderDataAM() function is working when I run only this function.

```
function insertOrderDataAM() {

  Logger.log("AM works!");
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('dev_AM PM PICK LIST');
  
  
  //1. Select data from Orderlist 
  //sw num - am
  var sn_range = ss.getRange('A1:A' + ss.getLastRow()); 
  var sn_data = sn_range.getValues(); // read value
  var sn_column = sn_data.map(function(row) { return row[0]; });

  //qty - am
  var q_range = ss.getRange('B1:B' + ss.getLastRow()); 
  var q_data = q_range.getValues(); 
  var q_column = q_data.map(function(row) { return row[0]; });

  //sku_lv - am
  var sku_range = ss.getRange('C1:C' + ss.getLastRow()); 
  var sku_data = sku_range.getValues();
  var sku_column = sku_data.map(function(row) { return row[0]; });

  var projectId = 'avlgear-erp-v-1-0';
  var datasetId = 'avlgear_erp';


  //2. Upload Order Input log table
  var insert_code = "INSERT INTO " + projectId + "." + datasetId + "." + "Orderlist_daily (sw_num, qty, sku_lv_list, ampm, md_date, rownum) VALUES "
  for(var i = 1; i < parseInt(sn_column.length); i++){
    if(sn_column[i] !== "" || q_column[i] !== "" || sku_column[i] !== ""){
       insert_code += "('" + sn_column[i] + "', "+ q_column[i] + ", '"  +  sku_column[i] + "', 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), " + i + "),";
    }
   } 
  insert_code = insert_code.slice(0, -1) + ";";
   

   Logger.log("AM insert_code : " + insert_code);
    const request_insert = {
        query : insert_code,
        useLegacySql: false
      };
    let queryResults_insert = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request_insert, projectId);
}
```

But If I use the function through onEdit() function, it is not working.

```
function onEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('dev_AM PM PICK LIST');
   var range = e.range;
   var column = range.getColumn();

  //if event = am input -> insert am order data
  if(column == 1){
    Logger.log("AM works?");
    insertOrderDataAM();
  }
}
```

At the "Oauth consent screen", I add the OAuth scopes to the project

I add these

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

And nothing changed.

And They were already set.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata
```